# Multithreaded string processing blows up with #threads

Tags: java, string, parsing, executorservice

I'm working on a multithreaded project where we have to parse some text from a file into a magic object, do some processing on the object, and aggregate the output. The old version of the code parsed the text in one thread and did the object processing in a thread pool using Java's `ExecutorService`. We weren't getting the performance boost that we wanted, and it turned out that parsing takes longer than we thought relative to the processing time for each object, so I tried moving the parsing into the worker threads.

This should have worked, but what actually happens is that **the time-per-object blows up as a function of the number of threads in the pool**. It's worse than linear, but not quite as bad as exponential.

I've whittled it down to a small example that (on my machine anyhow) shows the behavior. The example doesn't even create the magic object; it's just doing string manipulation. There's no inter-thread dependencies that I can see; I know `split()` isn't terribly efficient but I can't imagine why it would sh*t the bed in a multithreaded context. Have I missed something?

I'm running in Java 7 on a 24-core machine. Lines are long, ~1MB each. There can be dozens of items in `features`, and 100k+ items in `edges`.

Sample input:

```
1    1    156    24    230    1350    id(foo):id(bar):w(house,pos):w(house,neg)    1->2:1@1.0    16->121:2@1.0,3@0.5
```

Sample command line for running with 16 worker threads:

```
$ java -Xmx10G Foo 16 myfile.txt
```

Example code:

```
public class Foo implements Runnable {
String line;
int id;
public Foo(String line, int id) {
    this.line = line;
    this.id = id;
}
public void run() {
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+" Job start "+this.id);
    // line format: tab delimited                                                                
    // x[4]
    // graph[2]
    // features[m]      <-- ':' delimited                                              
    // edges[n]
    String[] x = this.line.split("\t",5);
    String[] graph = x[4].split("\t",4);
    String[] features = graph[2].split(":");
    String[] edges = graph[3].split("\t");
    for (String e : edges) {
        String[] ee = e.split(":",2);
        ee[0].split("->",2);
        for (String f : ee[1].split(",")) {
            f.split("@",2);
        }
    }                                                                    
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+" Job done "+this.id);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
    System.err.println("Reading from "+args[1]+" in "+args[0]+" threads...");
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(args[1]));
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    for(String line; (line=reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        pool.submit(new Foo(line, reader.getLineNumber()));
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(7,TimeUnit.DAYS);
}
}
```

---

**Updates:**

- Reading the whole file into memory first has no effect. To be more specific, I read the whole file, adding each line to an `ArrayList<String>`. Then I iterated over the list to create the jobs for the pool. This makes the substrings-eating-the-heap hypothesis unlikely, no?
- Compiling one copy of the delimiter pattern to be used by all worker threads has no effect. :(

---

**Resolution:**

I've converted the parsing code to use a custom splitting routine based on `indexOf()`, like so:

```
private String[] split(String string, char delim) {
    if (string.length() == 0) return new String[0];
    int nitems=1;
    for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == delim) nitems++;
    }
    String[] items = new String[nitems];
    int last=0;
    for (int next=last,i=0; i<items.length && next!=-1; last=next+1,i++) {
        next=string.indexOf(delim,last);
        items[i]=next<0?string.substring(last):string.substring(last,next);
    }
    return items;       
}
```

Oddly enough this does *not* blow up as the number of threads increases, and I have no idea why. It's a functional workaround though, so I'll live with it...

Comment: `pool.awaitTermination(7, TimeUnit.DAYS);` - One would hope this is sufficient.

Comment: Just a quick idea before I start delving into it deeper: have you tried reading the entire file (or a big chunk of it) into memory first, and then trying the parsing?

Comment: Just a hunch, but I would look into the implementation of `String#split(...)` and see how it performs when there are a large number of elements.  For example, it might assume a smaller number of elements and have to re-allocate the result array several times.

Comment: Have you tried profiling to determine what is actually slow?  `BufferedReader` (and `LineNumberReader` by extension) have to read each character from the input 1 by 1 until a line terminator is found. If that is the slow down, I wonder if `Scanner` would give better overall performance.

Comment: Can you change the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 7, `String.split()` uses `String.subString()` internally, which for "optimization" reasons does not create real new `Strings`, but empty `String` shells that point to sub-sections of the original one.

So when you `split()` a `String` into small pieces, the original one (maybe huge) is still in memory and may end up eating all your heap. I see you parse big files, this might be a risk (this has been changed in Java 8).

Given that your format is well-known, I would recommend parsing each line "by hand" rather that using `String.split()` (regex are really bad for performance anyway), and creating real new ones for sub-parts.

Comment: I would avoid creating strings completely if possible. If the format only allows basic ASCII characters (and from the sample it looks that way), you can work with bytes directly.

Comment: > In Java 7, String.split() uses String.subString() internally, which for "optimization" reasons does not create real new Strings  -- looks like it is valid only for early versions of java 7: http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/ ?

Answer (score 1):

String.split is actually using regular expressions to split, see:http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29
This means that you're compiling a whole bunch of regexes every iteration.

It'd probably be best to compile a pattern for the whole line once and then apply it to each line as it's read to parse them.  Either that, write your own parser that can look for character breaks instead of regex'ing it.

Comment: While the implementation details are hidden, for splits where the delimiter is a single character (and in some two character cases), the Oracle JRE in (at least) Java 7 internally implements this with `indexOf` and iteration rather than a regular expression.